# Can't Install IonCube loaders to Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ioncube

I have read several tutorials, and I have done everything (to my knowledge) correctly but I cannot get ionCube to install correctly for Xampp to use.

My `phpinfo` shows that I am running `PHP Version: 5.6.12 Compiler: MSVC11 Architecture: x86 Thread Safety: enabled` so I downloaded the `ioncube_loaders_win_vc11_x86.zip` file and uploaded the folder named `ioncube` to directory `php` and `htdocs`

I added the following line to the bottom of my `php.ini` file

`zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll"`

and I reset Apache

Those were the exact instructions of all tutorials as well as the ionCube Loader Wizard, but when I click to test the loader it says that The ionCube Loader is not currently installed successfully.

NOTE: I have Skype on my computer so my Apache Server uses ports 8080 and 4433, this was edited on `httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf, and on the Services and Port Settings Menu` I am not sure if this has anything to do with it or not, as I get no errors starting or stopping Apache.

I am not sure if I have skipped a step or what, but it refuses to work correctly for me.

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to windows permissions. Try locating the Loader dll in the same folder as other dll extensions within xamp, change the php.ini accordingly and restart. Also verify with a phpinfo that the php.ini you edited is the one that is being used.